# Generate guid for a table without a loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 100 records with no PK.

I need to add random GUID to it. Before:

```
    First Name   Last Name   GUID
      John         Smith
      Alex         Smith
etc
```

After:

```
    First Name   Last Name   GUID
      John         Smith    34234234gyerfw
      Alex         Smith    werwer32r23r
etc
```

Currently I can do it by:

Creating an identity column with values, then make a while loop and generate newid().
Any option on how to do this without a loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the GUID column as `NOT NULL` with a default of `NEWID()`

```
ALTER TABLE
    [dbo].[Text]

ADD [GUID] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWID()
```

This will automatically populate the existing rows, an you will not need to specify a guid when inserting records.

Comment: +1 - Assuming that every new record should be inserted with a random GUID and not a generated one, this is the way to go

Answer (score 9):

Just add the empty column and then do an `UPDATE`.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable
ADD GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

UPDATE YourTable
SET GUID = NEWID()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column and update the value or create a persisted column that has a default constraint with `NEWID()`

```
create table test (id int identity
, column1 uniqueidentifier not null default newid()
, column2 varchar(10))

insert into test(column2)
values ('a')

select * from test

alter table test
add column3 uniqueidentifier

update test
set column3 = NEWID()
```

Comment: You said "persisted column" but I don't think that's what you meant.